# Delete the euro (€) keyboard-shortcut via remapping the registry in windows

Tags: registry, keyboard-shortcuts

I´m trying to delete the <kbd>AltGR + E</kbd> shortcut for making a euro-sign `€` via remapping in the registry in windows.

I have found other that remapping in the registry is possible by searching other [Stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441821/2489106) and found out that there is a windows topic about the [same issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx). But I do not have the skills to code it myself :(

Do anybody have tried something like this? or have a solution for doing this in the registry?

I'm on a danish qwerty-keyboard on windows 7. <kbd>AltGR</kbd> is the right alt in a danish keyboard.

Comment: Hi, you will probably find better results if you took a search on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks! - I done it now and hope the best.